# Is there any research on applying state-space or dynamic linear models to forecasting equity risk premia?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, monte-carlo, risk-management, machine-learning

Is there any research on applying state-space or dynamic linear models to forecasting equity risk premia on a security-by-security basis with a medium term horizon (say 3 month to 12 months horizon)?

Markov Models are a special case of state-space models where the states are discrete. There's an avalanche of research on these MM's and HMM's (beginning with [Ryden](http://stat.wharton.upenn.edu/%7Esteele/Courses/956/Resource/HiddenMarkovModels/HMMApplications/.pdf) 1998) but it seems to me there are some advantages to taking an approach where the state is a continuous variable. I have seen [papers](https://doi.org/10.1214/10-STS325) by Johannes, Lopes, and Carvalho that focus on shorter-horizons and demonstrate the superiority of PL over MCMC methods.

Seems to me that this approach could capture the time-series dependence and cross-sectional dependencies in a way that traditional panel models cannot. Also, it seems that since history rhymes but does not repeat, a long-memory state-space model would be better than an HMM.

Before I go down this windy road I'm curious if anyone out there has already attempted this or if there is a weakness with this approach. For example, perhaps state-space or particle filtering models only work best when the forecast horizon is very short.

Comment: What does it mean to *forecast* the ERP on a single security?  Do you want to forecast the expected return over the risk free rate (in which case, this is equivalent to just forecasting expected return)?

Comment: Yes - it is forecasting expected return. They are risk premia in the sense that I am regressing on risk factors (value, size, beta).

Comment: Is this about dynamic regression of single security returns on risk factors (market, value, size, momentum, . .)? I see that as a 2-step process, first estimating betas for each security for each risk factor under consideration. Second; forecast expected returns to each risk factor and then use those forecasts coupled with betas to forecast expected returns to the security.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a paper by [Dangl, Halling, and Randl (2006)](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=887780&http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CFMQFjAH&url=http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/Delivery.cfm?abstractid=887780&rct=j&q=dynamic%20linear%20models%20%2bequity&ei=RdOJTp3fFpHPgAe22pH6Cg&usg=AFQjCNEztIlf6rHcGTxnXT9AFIjp863K5Q) that uses a dynamic linear model to forecast the equity risk premium.

Answer (score 4):

I think, as with many machine learning approaches to investing decision support, it depends largely on the data. With a good selection of features, yes dynamic models like you're talking about will probably do better than a simple linear regression; but then again, with a good selection of features, linear regression will probably work reasonably well, too. On the other hand, with a poor selection of features, you can use any statistical model in the world and it won't work -- simply put, you can't learn from patterns that aren't there.

That aside, you could probably also make gains by generalizing your search a bit from the models you describe to all Bayesian dynamic models.

Comment: Agreed. It just seems to me that state-space representations are more faithful representations of the dynamic nature of betas (vs. static OLS betas).

Comment: I was mainly using OLS as an example to illustrate the point that the data greatly overwhelms the importance of the model in the quant space. That said, I'd probably use a dynamic Bayesian model of some type as well.